# sails.js adding functionality to get function

Tags: sails.js

could somebody help me with adding new functionality to get function ? I'm using sails.js and mongoDB.

```
extend get: function(req, res)
{
    defaultget(req, res).done(function(err, data){
        // do some stuff with data
        // I need to return everything what it finds, adding new attribute to result
        // (I know how to do this), 
        // but still have an option to use default functionality for parsing 
        // query strings .

        res.json(changedData);
    })
}
```

Thank you for any answer.

Miro

Answer (score 2):

Badly worded question. We just needed to use query strings in our custom GET requests. Solution is easy and it's even in sailsjs documentation. Parsed query string from url is passed in req.query.

```
User.find(req.query).done(function(err, user) {
    \\ code after getting results affected by query string
};
```